# I can´t heredate from another implemented class in java

Tags: java, javafx

I have a problem (probably stupid) in relation with heritage in Java.
Right now I'm developing a GUI app with JavaFX. At this point I've created a class called `Controller`, where I declare my GUI elements by fxId and their own methods.

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

}

//---------- INICIALIZAMOS LOS ELEMENTOS POR SU ID ----------//
@FXML
private Button btnConectar;
@FXML
private Button btnDesconectar;
{...}
@FXML
private void clickBtnDesconectar(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Has sido DESCONECTADO");
}

@FXML
private void clickBtnContar(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Has CONTADO");
}
{...}
```

In other class I've my code for communicate with my PLC Siemens. There I've an heritage from class `Controller`. The reason is that I am going to use my GUI elements

```
import sample.Controller;

public class S7Service extends Controller{
public static final S7Client Client = new S7Client();
//public static byte[] Buffer = new byte[4];
{...}
```

Here we can access to GUI elements.

My problem appears at time to try to call the methods created at class `S7Service`, because doesn't work this declaration

```
import sample.S7Service;

public class Controller extends S7Service implements Initializable {

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

}

//---------- INICIALIZAMOS LOS ELEMENTOS POR SU ID ----------//
@FXML
private Button btnConectar;
{...}
```

The idea is to call the methods declared in `S7Service` in the button actions.

Thanks everybody

Comment: `S7Service` extends `Controller`, AND `Controller` extends `S7Service`.
That's not possible, Java only permits one-way inheritance.

Comment: I see it is hard for you to express yourself in English. More reason for you to post a [mcve]. Then I may be able to understand your problem.

Comment: About adxl's comment, how I can solve it? I would need put everythins in same class?

Comment: The idea is tidy the code, having a class for declare averything realted with GUI and in other class the rest of related with communication